# Adding events in JSON to fullcalendar

Tags: php, arrays, json, fullcalendar

I am trying to add events into my fullcalendar calendar with my json string. here is my code:

```
viewRender: function(view, element){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://www.example.com/get-events-json.php',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', data);
            },
            fail: function() {
                alert('There was an error while fetching events.');
            }
           });
    }
});
```

in my `success`, `data` is:

```
[{"title":"John Bobby","start":"2017-05-16T15:30:00","end":"2017-05-16T15:30:00"},{title":"Jason Kaple","start":"2017-05-20T17:30:00","end":"2017-05-20T17:30:00"}]
```

i tried to add it using `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', data);` as you can see but i get an error message in my console:

> http://www.example.com/[json (data)...] 404 (Not Found)

how can i fix this? are there any ways around this? thanks

Comment: Why not use the [events](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/) property?

Comment: @Mikey how would i use it with my `data` string and not a url?

Comment: why do you want to do this? If you specify an events feed via this method: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed or via custom function that updates events based on date: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_function then whenever the view is rendered and/or the date is changed then the events will be refreshed automatically anyway. No need to do anything during the viewRender event.

Comment: P.S. you asked: "how would i use it with my data string and not a url?", You wouldn't, you'd use the URL, which would return `data` directly to fullCalendar automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the data from an ajax call and after the render add the elements with addEvent

```
function addEvent(title, date){
    calendar.addEvent({
        title: title,
        start: date,
        allDay: true,
        color: 'green'
    });
}

for(event of events){
    addEvent(event.title, event.date)
}
```